# MS API Code Pack - Will it support future versions of DirectX?

Tags: directx

I'm working on deciding between Managed DirectX (through [MS API Codepack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack)), SlimDX library (managed wrapper for DirectX), XNA (managed wrapper++ for Directx9 only), or unmanaged Directx (20%+ extra development time).

So, the MS API Codepack interests me, because it has support for DirectX. However, I get a feeling that they might not support future versions with the Codepack. My thinking is that they just wanted something to support the version of DirectX that ships with Windows 7.

Is MSI API Code Pack DirectX functionality going to be updated as DirectX progresses?

Thanks

Comment: What future versions of DirectX? DirectX is dead, is all about XNA now.

Comment: XNA includes a wrapper around DirectX 9 in addition to extra functionality to facilitate swift game dev. XNA = Directx9. XNA cannot support DirectX 10, because XBOX360 hardware cannot support DirectX10. Saying DirectX is dead suggests that XNA is dead as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to know this.

However, I will say, I've been using SlimDX for a while now, and it's very, very well thought out.  The advantage there vs. the other options I've tried, include:

- Support for DirectX 9, 9Ex, 10, and 11
- Clean API - Very easy to port from DirectX samples, but still feels more like .NET
- 32 and 64 bit native versions
- Kept very up to date with DX SDK releases (usually within a couple of weeks of a new SDK, there's a new SlimDX version)

The Windows API code pack has a nice wrapper included, but is problematic for me since it's DX10+ only, so no XP support.